How often do we have lipschitz-continuous gradients for the objective function in practice(convergence of SGD)?
When I see proofs for the convergence of stochastic gradient descent then often it is assumed that the objective function is L-smooth(lipschitz-continuous gradients with constant L). Is this a reasonable assumption in practice?
